# Parsing JSON data gives JSONEXception: no value for content

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse JSON data and I've got a problem.

JSON:

```
{
    posts: [
    {
        post_id: "524c00d17227a2bd5a000002",
        channel_id: "524c00d17227a2bd5a000002",
        content: "any text here",
        image: {
            full_url: "http://url_to_thumb_image",
            thumb_url: "http://url_to_image",
            width: 1024,
            height: 758
        },.
```

My code:

```
try {
JSONArray json_posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");
for(int i = 0; i < json_posts.length(); i++) {                          
    JSONObject posts = json_posts.getJSONObject(i);
    String post_id = posts.getString("post_id");

    String post_content = posts.getString("content");
```

Error:

> JSONEXception: no value for content

Comment: I prefer using the Google GSON library to parse Json. Try it out:

Comment: post logcat error message..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are parsing the exact same JSON, but if it is the same (not a copy mistake), you should check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

And please add logcat.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for content

Comment: Did you double check if this is the same string you are processing? Because if  you are, you have a mistake. You have to have a closing JSONArray bracket, then another JSONObject closing bracket.